# How can I allow an anonymous user to generate an email to themself?

Tags: wordpress, email, checksum

I am using CiviCRM with WordPress.  I have just learned how to use "contact.checksum" to send an email to a user to safely let them edit their own personal info.  I can do that when they sign up for membership, or other events.  It's great!

I would like to have on my web site a link or button that allows users to fill in an email address and generate an email to that address (with the checksum link).  In other words, "click here to view and edit your data".

Ideally it would then confirm that the email was sent, but mostly I just want "send the checksum email to me please".  I have the message template ready, but how to I let the user trigger it?

Answer (score 3):

Someone else may have a simpler answer, but here's how I would do it:

- Install the extensions "CiviRules" and "Email API".
- Create a group called "Requested Data Update Email".
- Create an email template with whatever you want, including the checksum.
- Create a rule that when someone is added to the new group, they receive the email you just created.
- Create a profile (or a Caldera form, if you prefer) that requests email, and any other info you like.  Configure the profile so that submissions add the person to the new group.
- Optionally, add a second action to your rule to remove the person from the group, depending on whether you want them to be able to request the email multiple times or not.

Comment: I understand and have done this, up to the "profile that requests the email..."  step. 
 But do I offer folks that profile in Create mode or Edit mode.  If in Edit mode, then they get an error as soon as they visit it anonymously.  And if I offer it in create mode, it wants to CREATE a new user, and gives an error if they enter an already-in-use email.

What I want is for the user to have to enter an email address, without prompting.  If it exists in the database, then we add them to the new group, and all is well.  If it isn't, it should fail with an error message.

Comment: In the profile settings under advanced at the bottom there's a field "What to do upon duplicate match". You can choose to update the existing user. So try create mode, but with that setting.