# How can our users request an email with the contact.checksum links?

Tags: civirules, checksum

I am using CiviCRM 5.18.4 with WordPress 5.3.2.

We considered having our contacts all become WordPress Users, but decided to go the route of allowing folks to view and update their own contacts, or register for events, using {contact.checksum} to access their own data.

This works well when I initiate the process by sending them an email, but I want folks to be able to edit their own data on their own timeframe, without waiting for an email from me.  So I created a "RequestedLinks" group, and a CiviRule set to send an email with customized links whenever a user joins that group (and then immediately remove them from the group.  So far so good.

But how do I create a profile or form to let them trigger that rule?  I want folks to enter an email address, without prompting, and submit that form.  So I created a one-field profile.  But do I display that profile in "Create" or "Edit" mode?  Neither does what I want.

Once again, I feel I am struggling to invent something that is probably very easy...  So thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @david-hyman This seems like the same as your other question? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/34139/how-can-i-allow-an-anonymous-user-to-generate-an-email-to-themself/34140#34140

Comment: Sorry if I broke protocol.  My earlier question was answered, but my comment about it (basically asking for clarification of a key step) got no response, so I reposted it as fresh.  I probably should have waited longer for a response to the comment.

Comment: I agree stackexchange doesn't have a good way to advertise to the general audience that you've made a comment and you need something more. What sort of works is if you make the comment - that's fine - and then also edit your question to add some more info. That will push the question to the top of the front page again.

Comment: That's great to know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The create mode should do what you want - have you ticked "Standalone Form or Directory" in the profile settings?

In case that does not work, we are currently developing an extension that probably does what you need. Unfortunately it is still in development and not yet documented but you can find the code here: https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.selfservice